# React formik set initial values from firebase in modal

Tags: reactjs, firebase, formik

I have a form in a modal in react that edits an item. I am initializing the form with the props (data from firebase). I want the user to be able to edit the fields and click save to update the data in firebase.

The updating logic is working; however, when clicking save and submitting and then re-opening the same modal, the fields have the old data (pre-updating). My goal is to update the initial values when the firestore database is updated. The initial values aren't updating automatically (is it because they're passed as props?)

Here is my modal component:

```
export function Modal({
  id,
  title,
  topLabel,
  leftLabel,
  rightLabel,
  tags,
  notes,
  open,
  setOpen,
}) {

  const formFields = {
    initialValues: {
      title: title,
      topLabel: topLabel,
      leftLabel: leftLabel,
      rightLabel: rightLabel,
      tags: tags?.join(", "),
      notes: notes,
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    fields: [
      // array of input text fields here 
    ],
  };

  const handleUpdate = async (values) => {
    //  handle update logic here
  };

  return (
    <ModalContainer
      title="Edit item"
      open={open}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      formFields={formFields}
      onSubmit={handleUpdate}
      buttonLabel="Save"
    />
  );
};
```

The logic relating to formik in the `ModalContainer` component is:

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: formFields.initialValues,
    validationSchema: formFields.validationSchema,
    enableReinitialize: formFields.enableReInitialize,
    onSubmit: async (values, actions) => {
      try {
        setOpen(false);
        await onSubmit(values, actions);
      } catch (error) {
        setOpen(false);
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    formik.setTouched({}, false);
    formik.resetForm();
  }, [open]);
```

What am I doing wrong? How to solve this problem?